# Activity Start slowly

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Recently I met a strange problem,I start a activity from a service,but if I follow the steps :

1. enter a app
2. press home key to go back launcher
3. then trigger the service to start my activity

after above steps,the activity starts more slowly than normal way.Because I add a log in Activity's onCreate method.

normal way is same as above,except pressing home key.

Please help me  solve it.Thanks.

Comment: Do you press the back button? And if not, then do you override the `onResume` method? If its acting slow you must be doing some long process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the service and activity in different processes. I would also moving the logging into the service so it doesn't bind the UI. Use the process attribute for service in AndroidManifest.xml

Here's a snippit from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html):

> The name of the process where the service is to run. Normally, all
>   components of an application run in the default process created for
>   the application. It has the same name as the application package. The
>   element's process attribute can set a different default for all
>   components. But component can override the default with its own
>   process attribute, allowing you to spread your application across
>   multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you started from the IDE, hit back, and then tapped the launcher icon, you will be starting another instance of your app. This might help explain things.